# Powering hundreds of Adafruit's NeoPixels for a cosplay

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, amperage, led-matrix

My problem: I am trying to power a project with a 8x32px flexible matrix, 8x8px flexible matrix, 24px ring, 16px ring and 7px jewel (two of each), totalling up to a **whopping 734 pixels**. For my project I only am using a maximum of **408** though.

Each *lit* LED at 100% luminosity is either drawing 60mA (white), around 40mA (mixed) or 20mA (primary color). My color is in the mixed area (hot pink) so I used 40mA for my calculations, which already has a little overhead (since no primary color will be at 100% usage).

The amps needed here would be: 408px * 40mA / 1000 = **16.32A**

Each *unlit* LED draws ~1mA, so: 1mA * (734px - 408px) = **326mA**

Totalling up to **16.646A**.

Now, I could decouple the two 8x32px matrices from this, which would total to **12.88A for them alone** and making the other circuit a breeze to power, but those two 8x32 matrices (edit: not the two circuits, sorry for the confusion) need to be in sync, so they need to run off of one microcontroller and preferably one power supply (I don't want three power supplies spread out in my costume, no thanks).

Any suggestions on how I could accomplish this? I have looked through dozens of sites and even thought of using an RC car LiPo battery, but I don't know if that's overkill or even fits in my costume. Any help in this is greatly appreciated and if there are questions requesting more info, I am trying my best to supply it.

Comment: Are you using PWM? Or do you have some scheme to directly drive the LEDs at 100% duty?

Comment: From what I understand - this has to be portable? How long You want it to light? 16A continous from battery somwhere near Your body is not exactly save... And keep in mind, that everything (leds, power supplies etc.) will generate a lot of heat. Those leds are really bright - did You actually tried this in reality (how it will look?) Maybe consider lowering number of leds.

Comment: @jonk these are using PWM, yes

Comment: @HNYPOT I think we need to understand the PWM cycle better, then. Likely, your current/power calculations are different than you think. But I can't be sure.

Comment: @jonk NeoPixels are RGB leds with built in PWM controller so they are simply sent serial data stream to set the color. I am quite sure OP is correct that each RGB led set to full white draws 60mA.

Comment: @fifi_22 Yeah it should be portable, and yes I know, that's why I wanted to ask for help ^^ Sadly I can't use less LEDs than this, I already used as few as I could to make this costume work. Also since this project is nowhere near its completion, I don't know if I need those LEDs on the full 100% luminosity, maybe I can lower that instead. But for testing that I'd need a bunch more stuff (they'll be behind a black dyed visor that will be vacuformed and I still need all the equipment for that)

Comment: So roughly 16A at 5V, that is 80 Watts. So a typical laptop, power tool or camera battery that is rated for 80Wh ( e.g 20V 4Ah) should power it for an hour, just for reference. Also note that for power distribution, it could make more sense to have multiple smaller buck converters than a single 16A buck converter. Routing long runs of high currents of 5V needs thicker wire than long runs of low currents at 20V battery voltage.

Comment: @Justme And how would I go about doing that, exactly? This is the first time I've heard of buck converters haha

Comment: @Justme Geez, that's a lot for an average. Thanks for the info.

Comment: It was more like to give you an idea that if it is doable or not. If you need it to run for 10 hours straight, you'd need to carry a backpack filled with 10 batteries that will weigh 5kg. And the 80W of LEDs will heat the wearer up constantly at 80W unless there is some thermal management to transfer the heat to air or something. So you need to look at this project from many different angles, one of it is how long a person can be wrapped in thermal insulating plastic layer with a 80W heater in it.

Comment: NeoPixels really aren't that easy to drive in large sizes huh... I mean I'd be fine with thicker wires. And the thermal part is also already taken care of. But that battery bulk just barely seems airport proof lol

Comment: Since that is going to be absurdly bright, I would try to lower the brightness to reduce heat/power. Either decrease the PWM ratio on all channels equally (scale so that 255 is 50% PWM ratio) or maybe try reducing the voltage (e.g. generate 4 or 4.5v if the neopixel controllers can handle it).

Comment: If by neopixel led you mean WS2812 you can solve the problem by software. You did not mention what kind of controller in use.

Comment: Measure the actual consumption at your target brightness, it may be a lot lower. One of those phone extended battery packs that outputs USB should be able to manage an amp or two.

Comment: @user263983 I will most likely go for an Arduino Nano Every!

Comment: @user1850479 Yeah, that's the one part I still have no clue of how it will end up in the costume. I would like to tone down the brightness but I gotta see if the LEDs are still visible under the visor, diffusors and whatnot when doing so

Comment: @HNYPOT so if you have own controller it is easy to control load.

Comment: From Adafruit: I’m often asked for help on a portable or wearable project, the designer insisting “it has to be completely covered in NeoPixels, and able to have them all on white at 100% brightness. But when I do the math it comes out to 1.21 gigawatts. Help!” There's a [whole tutorial about reducing power consumption](https://learn.adafruit.com/sipping-power-with-neopixels?view=all) and one about [battery power for LED pixels](https://learn.adafruit.com/battery-power-for-led-pixels-and-strips?view=all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This started as a comment but got a bit long;

Neopixels / Ws2812s need a 5V **regulated** supply and do indeed draw 50-60mA per unit when at full brightness.

This is enough to see significant voltage drop down a long string or tape (guess how I know) so the LEDs at the far end of a strip light up red because there's insufficient voltage for the green & blue LEDs to strike up. So, you need a robust power feed to your various "groups" of LEDs - and remember voltage drop gets worse the lower your power supply voltage. 12A down a long wire or PCB track is a significant amount of power.

I would either use one large-ish RC Lipo battery and a few DC-DC (buck) converters near each "group" of LEDs (EG you feed 14V or 18V from the LIPO to a small DC-DC that powers one LED matrix - that way any drop in the wires doesn't affect the metrix) or I'd source a few USB power banks and attach those to the various groups if that's workable - USB power banks do the voltage regulation and easy recharging for you, at the cost of bulk & expense.

Synchronising with your micro is a bit of a challenge if you distribute power supplies, but commoning the grounds solves one side and since the LED control is omni-directional (transmit only), you could maybe use opto-isolators at the LED end to drive the LED data decoupled from the microcontroller voltage. There may be other ways - there's plenty of optical and digital isolation ICs and little modules/boards out there from China that would likely solve your problem.

You can see voltage drop over cable length/size here to give you some indications;

http://fuddymuckers.co.uk/tools/cablecalc.html

12A at 5V gives **1V drop per metre** on 1mmsq cable - if you source that same 60w of power from an 18V battery and only regulate it down at to 5V at the last minute you only lose 0.28V/metre in that 1mmsq cable.

Answer (score 1):

WS2812 or similar is very bright. Do some test before choosing numbers. I powered 300 pieces, each chip got summary 5 of 256x3 and got enough light in enlightened room. Consumption is 0.5A and voltage drop in 5 meter string is 350mA. Run power to each piece of your assembly separate wires from PS. Whan power disconnected, chips loosing data. Best way to turn off and keep it synchronized write "0" but keep data in controller memory. One chip will consume less then 1mA. Controller is rewriting data to LEDs with some time intervals.